# How to return height and width of a base 64 encoded graphic using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am adding an image to my canvas background using a base 64 encoded graphic. My question is how to return the width and height of the encoded graphic `image_png` so I can set the width and height of the canvas to the same.

```
import tkinter as tk    

image_png = """
R0lGODlhIAAgALMAAAAAAAAAgHCAkC6LV76+vvXeswD/ANzc3DLNMubm+v/6zS9PT6Ai8P8A////
/////yH5BAEAAAkALAAAAAAgACAAAAS00MlJq7046803AF3ofAYYfh8GIEvpoUZcmtOKAO5rLMva
0rYVKqX5IEq3XDAZo1GGiOhw5rtJc09cVGo7orYwYtYo3d4+DBxJWuSCAQ30+vNTGcxnOIARj3eT
YhJDQ3woDGl7foNiKBV7aYeEkHEignKFkk4ciYaImJqbkZ+PjZUjaJOElKanqJyRrJyZgSKkokOs
NYa2q7mcirC5I5FofsK6hcHHgsSgx4a9yzXK0rrV19gRADs=
"""
master=tk.Tk()
master.geometry("100x100")

canvas=tk.Canvas(master)
canvas.grid()

photo=tk.PhotoImage(data=image_png)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")

master.mainloop()
```

I thought the solution could be something like the following (to make an example):

```
height, width = photo.height(), photo.width()
canvas.create_image(height = height, width = width, image=photo, anchor="nw")
```

Comment: you say "I thought the solution could be...". Did you try that solution? What happened?

Answer (score 3):

Use `width`, `height` method of the `PhotoImage`:

```
...
photo = tk.PhotoImage(data=image_png)
print(photo.width())  # => 32
print(photo.height())  # => 32
...
```